# Manejo de Errores - MongoDB y NodeJS - Async/Await

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, async-await, server

Estoy realizando una serie de prácticas con **MongoDB** y **NodeJS**, dentro de un entorno **Serverless Offline**, con el empleo de **async/await** para mejorar tanto el rendimiento como aspecto del código. La cuestión es que no estaría logrando manejar los errores de conexión cuando la base de datos no está disponible.

El código es el siguiente:

Controlador que retorna los productos una vez obtenidos (ahora lo hice simple a modo de ejemplo)

```
'use strict';

const { status } = require('../../helpers/status');
const { read } = require('../../models/product/read_product_model');

module.exports = {
    async GetProducts() {
        const products = await read()
            .then(prods => (prods.length > min ? status(200, prods) : status(404, { status: 'NOT PRODUCTS FOUND' })))
            .catch(() => status(503, 'INTERNAL SERVER ERROR'));
        return products;
    },
    async GetOne() {
        return status(200, 'ok');
    }
};
```

Modelo

```
'use strict';

const { run } = require('../../config/connection');

module.exports = {
    async read() {
        const client = await run()
            .catch(() => new Error());
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db('baseMicroservices');
        const products = db.collection('products');
        const search = products.find({});
        const resp = await search.toArray();
        return resp;
    }
};
```

La configuración para **MongoDB**

```
'use strict';

const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://mydatabase/baseMicroservices';

module.exports = {
    async run() {
        return new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    }
};
```

Por el momento funciona de maravilla, el único inconveniente es que no tengo mucha idea de cómo capturar el error cuando la base esté caída, por ejemplo. En el caso de que haya que cambiar todo el código o exista una mejor forma de encarar el problema, con la solución a este inconveniente en particular, más que agradecido.

Comment: No veo cómo `async/await` *mejora el rendimiento*, es más bien lo contrario.

Answer (score 0):

para capturar un error, puedes hacerlo como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
GetProducts() {
        const products = read()
                          .catch(status(404, 'error'))
                          .then(() => status(200, products));
}
```

Y si tienes un método main para devolver que está corriendo tu programa hazlo síncrono:

```
const main =()=> {
  return GetProducts(); // Ejecutamos desde un metodo sincrono.
}
```

Espero que te funcione esta aproximación!

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Gonzalo! Gracias de antemano. Está bueno lo que me sugerís. Recién hice la prueba con dicho código, me solucionaste la parte del **return** desde el controlador que antes no podía acceder para devolverle al handler de **Serverless**. Lo que si, la conexión recién la saqué apropósito pero el server se queda colgado hasta los 30 segundos... Voy a hacer la prueba desde el Modelo y verificar si puedo retornar un mensaje de error de conexión con lo que sugerís

Comment: Me alegro !! , para elevar un error hazlo con throw  :) y así lo podemos capturar en el catch . Te dejo este enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con async await, intenta poner el await dentro de un try.

```
Try {
    const client = await run();
} catch (e) {
    Consolé.error(e) 
}
```